# Add kerberos ticket to a soap request

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl, kerberos

I have a problem that is as follows:

- I have a webservice, and I want to authenticate with Kerberos.

I add in my visual studio wsdl by adding a service reference ... it creates a proxy class, so to speak, and reference.cs can invoke the service.

What he wanted now was to get a Kerberos ticket from the user logged into pc, and then add this ticket in the soap request and invoke the service.

Can anyone help me how can I do this?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: I was trying to do was to modify the web.config of the webservice to put the webservice kerberos. But having realized that many had to change all webservices. 
So wanted the application client to enter the soap header in the kerberos ticket, but do not know how ... it has nothing to do with what I was trying. First I have to get the ticket, anyone know how?

Comment: Do some research. If you had the ticket, where would you put it? Where do other credential-related objects go? What are the options for different kinds of credentials? Where are they specified? _How_ are they specified. If you do a little work, we'll be glad to help you the rest of the way.

Comment: Yes've googled ... 
I have the ticket, then I'd have to put it in the soap header to the service request.